# Trailing slash causes 404, can I fix using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

The offending URLs are:

- (Doesn't work) http://alltheragefaces.com/face/surprised-wut/
- (Works) http://alltheragefaces.com/face/surprised-wut

The .htaccess rule I have for these types of URLs looks like:

`RewriteRule ^face/(.*)$ face.php?term=$1`

What can I do to make both of these URLs to go to the same page?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^face/(.*)/?$ face.php?term=$1`

Comment: You could just `rtrim($_GET['term'], '/')` inside your PHP script. Although @Grexis regex way is arguably better.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Your solution is actually the one that worked. For some reason the .htaccess fix didn't work. Want to add as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Jake it would be best if you can find a .htaccess way - try @Grexis' rule but surround the `/` with parenthesis - `^face/(.*)(/+)?$` - or maybe `^face/(.*)/*$`

Comment: Oh wait I have just realised what the problem is, it's a greedy `*`, try `^face/(.*?)/*$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The first line says: "if it's not a directory" (because then a trailing slash would have meaning). The second line says: redirect everything from start to the trailingslash and end to everything that was in there, without the trailing slash.

Put your own `RewriteRule` in there (below that one, not above) so your normal redirect still works after the trailing slash was removed.

(this one will obviously work for `/body/` too, and not only for `/face/`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this rule which is slightly modified to maintain any subfolder structure

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the already accepted answer?