# Why does Apache throw a Forbidden error when using RewriteRule and going to an URL with a trailing slash at its end?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, trailing-slash

I want to build a search page for my application, and I am using `.htaccess` to make URLs look better. The search page is located at `localhost/search`. Furthermore, two optional parameters can be appended at the end of the URL, like this: `localhost/search/post/12345`. However, when no parameters are appended, only a trailing slash (`localhost/search/`), Apache throws a Forbidden error. I am not sure why this is happening as there is no folder named `search` on the server.

To better illustrate my problem, here are the links that work and the ones that don't are as follows:

**Working:**

- `localhost/search`
- `localhost/search/post`
- `localhost/search/post/`
- `localhost/search/post/12345`
- `localhost/search/post/12345/`

**Not working:**

- `localhost/search/`

`search.php` is located in the root directory along with the `.htaccess` file. So here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extension-less php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Search parameters
RewriteRule ^search?/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)?/?$ search.php?type=$1&data=&2

# 404 error
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347011/14226941) helpful answer on StackOverflow. In the `.htaccess` file, I changed the following lines:

```
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

to:

```
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```